# I would want to generate a dummy variable called treated if an id is present in two years

Tags: r, time, dummy-variable

I have a df like this in R

```
 year id value  time
 2012  1  180     1
 2012  1  149     1
 2010  2  131     0
 2010  2  120     0
 2010  2  120     0
 2010  2   16     0
 2010  2  120     0
 2012  2   50     1
```

I would want to create a dummy variable that is 1 if id is in both years in 2010 and 2012 in the  column year, just like this

```
 year id value  time both
 2012  1  180     1   0
 2012  1  149     1   0
 2010  2  131     0   1 
 2010  2  120     0   1
 2010  2  120     0   1
 2010  2   16     0   1
 2010  2  120     0   1
 2012  2   50     1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code first creates list holding all `ids` vs. `years`, then checks which `ids` are same for all the available `years`. Such resulting `ids` are then tested for match with `id` column in dataframe and saved as 0/1 values in a separate column named `both_resp`:

```
df <- ... your dataframe ...

idsPerYear <- split(df$id, df$year)
idsInAllYears <- Reduce(intersect, idsPerYear)
df$both_resp <- as.numeric( df$id %in% idsInAllYears )
```

or an alternative with hardcoded values:

```
df$both_resp <- as.numeric( 
    df$id %in% intersect( 
        df[ df$year == 2010, "id"], 
        df[ df$year == 2012, "id"]
    )
)
```